# Angular 2 Access Router-outlet component Function from Parent

Tags: angular

I am trying to access Home Component function callFromParent() which is rendered inside  using Try Child Button in Appcomponent. I am getting error as "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'callFromParent' of undefined"

I tried similar Questions but nothing worked for me. Please Help.

[image: Error]

```js
// App Component

@ViewChild(HomeComponent) homeComponent: HomeComponent;

  callChild() {
    this.homeComponent.callFromParent();
  }
  
  
 //Home Component
 
 callFromParent() {
    alert('Hi');
  }
```

```html
<!-- App Component -->

<button (click)="callChild()">Try Child</button>
<router-outlet>
  <home-component></home-component>
</router-outlet>
```

Comment: why are you using router-outlet when you are specifying home component selector as well??

Comment: I have my current project structure like that.. its created by someone previously working

Comment: I guess you should use either or, one of two not both, if you are using router outlet then you can create a shared service which will invoke the method in child (home component) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other mentioned, it makes no sense to have both child tag and router-outlet for the same component. But reaching a component behind a `router-outlet` can be done with `ContentChild`:

app.component:

```ts
import { ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

selector: ...
templateUrl: ...
providers: [ HomeComponent ]

// ...

@ContentChild(HomeComponent)
private homeComponent : HomeComponent;

callChild() {
  this.homeComponent.callFromParent();
}
```

Comment: can i get more details on contentchild. some reference to more topics like this.

Comment: Just googling you'll find some topics, maybe this can shed some light on the difference between ViewChild(ren) and ContentChild(ren) :) http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [interaction using local variable](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable) (instead of using ViewChild ) as follows

```
<!-- App Component -->

<button (click)="home.callFromParent()">Try Child</button>
<home-component #home></home-component>
```

Comment: I guess `home-component` gets loaded via router itself, how can you add `local template variable` over it?